# Eclipse "Write Occurrences" Click Highlight Delay

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting, text-editor, find-occurrences

How do I decrease the "Write Occurrences" delay in Eclipse? When I click a variable in the editor, it takes a while before it highlights all instances of it. I want to make this instantaneous.

Comment: I don't think there's a configurable delay, it's just the time it takes for the job to find all the occurrences in your AST. It's pretty fast in the Java editor I find.

Comment: It's not fast. It takes 200ms atleast which is quite annoying.

Comment: There's a delay before it kicks in and tries to do the highlighting.  The alternative is to spend as much CPU as needed to keep up with every keystroke and mouse-click you do within the text.

Answer (score 0):

There is a delay before algorithm for computing occurrences kicks in. The important part is that this delay is not fixed (ie 200ms).

My personal experience with Eclipse gui shows this: After eclipse is freshly started, the delay is minimal, let's say 200 ms. But if during working with gui eclipse ONCE hits a scenario where computation of occurences takes more than 200 ms, it increases delay 2x, ie to 400 ms. After this you cannot shorten the delay to 200 ms any other way than restarting the gui. That's really annoying.

The same goes on if some background thread blocks gui even more, and delay grows to 800ms, 1600 ms, etc. (there were times where delay was about 3s). This leads me to periodically restarting eclipse, because I'm quite dependent on variable highlighting. There is no solution AFAIK.